# add views to list view in navigation drawer

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

So I'm trying to add the navigation drawer to my app so as a beginning I created a sample project with the android navigation drawer example.

From what I see, they use the list adapter to add items to the navigation drawer.

I want to add a few more things to it:

- A text View in the header.
- A button
- A bunch of items separated by categories like: events, messages and more...

I tried to use the addView method but the app crashes.

Then I used the addHeaderView which added the text view in the header but that's not enough...

What's the right way to add the views to the list view?

Comment: What crash did you get? Show logcat

Comment: @ImAtWar, "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is the SOLUTION

android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout is an amazing UI Element in the Android History. Suppose you've two ChildViews in android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout. Then the First Child is the LEFT DRAWER and NEXT CHILD IS THE RIGHT DRAWER

Here's a sample, read code carefully and understand the structure.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.rh.bookmany"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <!--What ever your want in the Right drawer, put it in  below RelativeLayout -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white" >

        <!-- TO SHOW FRAGMENTS -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mFragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>





    <!--What ever your want in the LEFT drawer, put it in  below RelativeLayout -->

    <!-- LEFT DRAWER -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/whatYouWantInLeftDrawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/black" >

        <!-- Cover or Banner -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlBanner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- Cover Pic Container -->
            <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                >
                <!-- Cover Picture -->
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCoverPic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/dummy_desc"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/skrillex" />

                <!-- Tint -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/llCoverTint" 
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    ></LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <!-- Profile Pic Container -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llProfilePicContainer"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                 <com.rh.bookmany.view.MLRoundedImageView
                        android:id="@+id/civProfilePic"
                        android:src="@drawable/tony"
                        android:layout_height="65dp"
                        android:layout_width="65dp"
                        />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvUserEmail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvUserName"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvUserName"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvUserName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/llProfilePicContainer"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/llProfilePicContainer"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- ListMenu -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_menu_container"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/rlBanner"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/nyc_black"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/border_black"
            android:dividerHeight="@dimen/divider_height"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/item_selector" >
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MLRoundedImageView.java**

```
package your.package.name;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MLRoundedImageView extends ImageView {

    public MLRoundedImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MLRoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MLRoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Log.d("X","MLRoundedImageView ONDRAW");

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();

        Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
        canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    }

    public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
        Bitmap sbmp;

        if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius) {
            float smallest = Math.min(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
            float factor = smallest / radius;
            sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int)(bmp.getWidth() / factor), (int)(bmp.getHeight() / factor), false);
        } else {
            sbmp = bmp;
        }

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(radius, radius,
                Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xffa19774;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, radius, radius);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
        canvas.drawCircle(radius / 2 + 0.7f,
                radius / 2 + 0.7f, radius / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }

}
```

The above code can produce exactly the below output.

- Note that with ONLY XML, you can't make something like this. though you have to do something in your Activity with JAVA.*

[image]

Comment: dude, that's awesome!! one question thou, what is "com.rh.bookmany.view.MLRoundedImageView"?

Comment: That's nothing general, It's an ImageView which i used to get the RoundedCornered ImageView. In otherwords its a CustomView to get Circled Image.

Comment: Ohh you want it, wait a second.

Comment: Code Updated, I assume that you knw package naming rules for a customview.

Comment: hi all, I have drawer layout inside that I have some stuff, the problem is it is not scrolling I tried with listview also still it is not scrolling. please help!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Navigation Drawer, its better to work with Fragments.

Here is the [Github link](https://github.com/rohaniitr/Sliding_Module) to the Navigation Drawer I created few days back. Its code is easy to understand. And you can get back if you fin any problem.

If you want to understand its working, you can get the [documentation here.](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

Comment: Its not a library. Its a simple code. You create separate XMLs and Java classes for each item in Navigation Drawer. Then create 1 XML for Navigation Drawer itself, and then in MainActivity you can call those classes and get them working. You need to know about DrawerLayout for this. But its easy. You can get it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)